# sonar runner cannot add the same measure

Tags: sonarqube, runner

ello,
I am doing my code analysis through sonar runner previously I am getting the following error.when I run teh command of **sonar-runner**
Any help???

```
SonarException: Can not add twice the same measure on org.sonar.api.resources.Project
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not add twice the same measure on org.sonar.api.resources.Project@549154f9[id=22,key=DistanceConver
ter-Net:DistanceConverter,qualifier=BRC]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@70d1a353[id=<null>,metricKey=profile,metric=Metric[id=144,formula=<null>,key=profile,description=Selected quality profile,type=
DATA,direction=0,domain=General,name=Profile,qualitative=false,userManaged=false,enabled=true,origin=JAV,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=<null>,optimizedBestValue=false,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=f
alse],value=5.0,data=Sonar way,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,tendency=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<nu
ll>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL]
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:288)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:151)
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Could you mark my answer below as correct to help next readers?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have 2 or more projects with same name. Rename your projects to have distinct names will help.

In your case, Sonar specifically indicates that the project name `Net:DistanceConverter` is confusing.